# What's the best way to "embed" a page number in a URL?

Tags: django, url, web-applications

I'm developing a blog application using Django. Currently, the URL `/blog/` displays the front page of the blog (the first five posts). Visitors can then browse or "page through" the blog entries. This portion is mapped to `/blog/browse/{page}/`, where `page`, of course, is an integer that specifies which "page" of blog entries should be displayed.

It's occurred to me, though, that perhaps the "page number" should be an attribute of the querystring instead (e.g., `/blog/browse/?page=2`), since the content of the browse pages is not static (i.e., as soon as I add another post, `/blog/browse/2/` will have different contents than it had *before* the post was added). This seems to be the way sites like Stack Overflow and Reddit do things. For example, when paging through questions on Stack Overflow, a ["page" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest) is used; likewise, Reddit uses a ["count" attribute](http://www.reddit.com/?count=25&after=t3_7q8et).

Extending this thinking, I realize that I use the same template to render the contents of both `/blog/` and `/blog/browse/`, so it might even make sense to just use a URL like `/blog/?page=2` to page through the contents of the blog.

Any suggestions? Is there a "standard" way of doing this, or at least a "best practice" method to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use the GET URL parameter, as in URL?pg=#. It's very common and provides a standard visual clue to users about what is going on. If, for instance, I want to bookmark one of those pages or make an external link, I know without thinking that I can drop the pg parameter to point at the "latest" front-page index. With an embedded #, this isn't as obvious... do I leave off the parameter? Do I always have to set it to 1? Is it a different base URL entirely? To me, having pagination through the GET parameter makes for a slightly more sensible URL, since there's an acceptable default if the parameter is omitted and the parameter doesn't affect the base URL.

Also, while I can't prove it, it gives me the warm fuzzy feeling that Google has a better chance at figuring out the nature of that page's content (i.e. that it is a paginated index into further data, and will potentially update frequently) versus a page # embedded inside the URL, which will be more opaque.

That said, I'd say this is 99% personal preference and I highly doubt there's any real functional difference, so go with whatever is easier for and fits in better with your current way of doing things.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that my opinion is Django specific... I have a few Django apps so I'm relatively familiar with the way they build their URLs, and I still use a "pg" GET parameter with those apps rather than embedding it in the URL directly.

Answer (score 4):

For my money, the best general purpose approach to this issue is to use the [django-pagination](http://code.google.com/p/django-pagination/) utility.  It's incredibly easy to use and your URLs should have the format you desire.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are two things going on. A static page, that won't change and can be used for permalinking, like an article, as well as a dynamic page that will update frequently. There is no reason you cannot use both. URL rewriting should allow this to work quite nicely. There's no reason to let the implementation control the interface, there is always at least one way to skin every cat.

Comment: I do use a permanent URL to link to a specific post; I'm just wondering about the paging/browsing aspect of the application.